# Delphi: Send data through one socket multithreading

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Can some one give me idea how to send and receive data thru one connection in multithreading.

The model look like this:

[image: Model]

What I know is that if all three clients are sending data at the same time, "client X" will receive a merge of all received data, and "client X" can't separate that data to identify which part is from which client.

Delphi 2010, Indy, Win7.

*Sorry if my english is bad, I hope you understand the idea.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement a locking mechanism, such as a critical section or mutex, to prevent multiple threads from writing to the socket at exactly the same time.

When receiving data that is destined for multiple threads, you need to do the reading in one thread only, and have it pass on the data to the other threads as needed.

Either way, you need to frame your data so the receiver knows where one message ends and the next begins. Either be sending a message's length before sending the message contents, or by sending a unique delimiter in between messages that will never appear in the messages themselves.