# How do I protect my Indy socket writes with a critical section?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, mutex

```
cs.Acquire;
try
   AContext.Connection.Socket.Write(packet);
finally
   cs.Release;
end;
```

or

```
EnterCriticalSection(cs);
   AContext.Connection.Socket.Write(packet);
LeaveCriticalSection(cs);
```

I trying to send my packet to server in thread, but I have 20 threads which is also sending data to same connection socket. I'm try use Critical Section or Mutex, and they both don't work, I receive the garbage when all threads are sending.

it's all about my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440499/delphi-send-data-through-one-socket-multithreading)

Packet looks like this:

LengthData

0000000010HelloWorld

Server receive data:

```
ReadBytes(10);

len := (Then remove zeros from begining);

ReadBytes(len); // data.
```

Sometimes I receive garbage in ReadBytes(10), it's a mix of Length+Data something like: "10Hellowor"

If I send data to server using only one thread, all works fine, every time.
If many threads is sending, all goes wrong.

Comment: Need more code - the CS/mutex should work OK.  Why 'remove zeros from begining' - strToInt() should remove the leading zeros anyway.

Comment: Is your critical section object shared between all threads? Is it a global variable? Does your program work with a single thread?

Comment: The smart way to do this is have one thread do the talking, and the other threads store packets for sending in a control object. You would use the critical section for preventing clashes in the control object.

Comment: @mj2008 +1 for queuing the write requests/objects to a single write thread.  This makes debugging easier and restricts the number of blocked threads in the case of the write call bocking temporarily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CS/mutex locks work just fine when used properly.  Make sure that your threads are locking the *same* CS/mutex instance, not separate instances. Since you are sending the data from the server side, I would suggest using the `OnConnect` event to create a per-connection CS and store it in the `TIdContext.Data` property, and the `OnDisconnect` event to free it, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Data := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Data.Free;
  AContext.Data := nil;
end;
```

Then you can do this when needed:

```
TCriticalSection(AContext.Data).Acquire;
try 
   AContext.Connection.Socket.Write(packet); 
finally 
  TCriticalSection(AContext.Data).Release;
end;
```

A slightly more encapsulated usage would be to derive a new class from `TIdServerContext` instead, eg:

```
type
  TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext)
  private
    CS: TCriticalSection;
  public
    constructor Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TThreadList = nil); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SendPacket(const AData: TIdBytes); // or whatever parameters you need
  end;

constructor TMyContext.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TThreadList = nil);
begin
  inherited;
  CS := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

destructor TMyContext.Destroy;
begin
  CS.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyContext.SendPacket(const AData: TIdBytes);
begin
  CS.Acquire;
  try
    Connection.IOHandler.Write(AData);
  finally
    CS.Release;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.ContextClass := TMyContext;
end;
```

Then you can do this when needed:

```
TMyContext(AContext).SendPacket(packet);
```